# How can I create a enum from another enum in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums

Is there a way having a enum like

```
enum Foo: Int {
   case unknown
   case secondCase
   case thirdCase
}
```

To create another enum to contain only some specific cases of that enum?

Something like

```
enum Bar: Int {
   case Foo.unknown
   case Foo.secondCase
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no, but you can do this:

```swift
enum Bar: Int {
    case unknown
    case secondCase
}

enum Foo: Int {
    case bar(Bar)
    case thirdCase
}
```

You'd have to implement your own Equatable, Hashable, etc., conformance, but it could be done. Enums are not designed for it, though, and neither is the language.

In the future, someone could propose this on the [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org), where the community makes proposals to evolve the language.